# Perform action if drop down item is selected VSTO Outlook using C# and XML

Tags: c#, xml, outlook, ms-office, vsto

I created a simple drop down menu in a ribbon.xml file.  This menu has 4 items which can be selected by the user.  The XML I am using can be seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="TabAddIns" label="testing">
        <group id="TestSettings" label="Settings">
          <dropDown id="trainingDropDown" label="Select Data Set">
            <item id="item1" label="lable 1" />
            <item id="item2" label="lable 2" />
            <item id="item3" label="lable 3" />
            <item id="item3" label="lable 4" />
          </dropDown>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

How can I check to see which item within the drop down menu is currently selected using C#?  i.e. :

```
if(item1 == selected)
{  
    //do stuff
}
```

I have implemented actions within VSTO code using toggle buttons and "onAction" previously, unfortunately I cannot figure out how to accomplish the same thing using drop down menus.

Comment: `dropDown` has `onAction` too.

Comment: I did not realize that, thank you for pointing that out!  I am not sure how I would utilize that to tell which item in the menu is selected though.  For a button, I use a Boolean variable to check whether or not it has been pressed and then select the code to run based on that variable.  How can I do the same thing with the items inside the drop down menu?

Comment: Did you try it? It's pretty straightforward. Here's some [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd947478%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and a similar question that is fairly close to being a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695716/get-selected-items-tag-of-ribbon-combobox-control-in-vsto-vb-net/38723860.

Comment: Ah, there is the documentation I was looking for! Thank you.  I will try it when I am back in the office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chris for pointing me in the right direction.  I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do using the drop down menu "onAction" callback.  To do this, all I had to do was add "onAction" into my XML like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="TabAddIns" label="testing">
        <group id="TestSettings" label="Settings" onAction = "SelectModel">
          <dropDown id="trainingDropDown" label="Select Data Set">
            <item id="item1" label="label 1" />
            <item id="item2" label="label 2" />
            <item id="item3" label="label 3" />
            <item id="item3" label="label 4" />
          </dropDown>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

From here, I created a function in my ribbon class called "SelectModel"  (corresponding with the onAction name specified above). Getting the item index as a parameter, I was able to output different messages depending on which drop down item was selected.

```
public void SelectModel(Office.IRibbonControl control, string selectedId, int SelectedItemIndex)
        {
            if (SelectedItemIndex == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("first item selected");
            }
            else if (SelectedItemIndex == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("second item selected");
            }
            else if(SelectedItemIndex == 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("third item is selected");
            }
            else if (SelectedItemIndex == 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("fourth item is selected");
            }
        }
```

This results in the output shown here: [image: VSTO dropdown menu output]

Comment: I note the OnAction is applied to the group in which the dropdown lives, not the dropdown itself. Is that intentional?